# PHP LFTP data mirror output

Tags: php, file-structure, bash, ftp

I'm using a Linux local computer and need to backup/mirror some very large file structures regularly. I only have access to SFTP.

I was after a simple one click solution. I originally tried to write the little script in BASH but I've never used it before and am not up to scratch with the syntax so I resorted to PHP. (I do understand PHP is not designed for this kind of work, but I'm on a tight time scale and don't have the time to get into BASH atm)

```
<?php
//init
parse_str(implode('&', array_slice($argv, 1)), $_GET);
$error = array();

$lPrefix         = '/home/hozza/Sites/';
$archiveLocation = '/home/hozza/Backups/';

$lDir = isset($_GET['l']) ? $_GET['l'] : $error[] = 'Local Directory Required';
$rDir = isset($_GET['r']) ? $_GET['r'] : $error[] = 'Remote Directory Required';
$bookmark = isset($_GET['b']) ? $_GET['b'] : $error[] = 'lftp Bookmark Required';

//Check for args
if(count($error) == 0) {
    $archiveName = end(explode('/', $lDir)) . '_' . date('Y-m-d_H-i');

    //Validate local dir
    if(is_dir($lPrefix . $lDir)) {

        //preserve Sublime Text 2 config SFTP files
        $ST2_SFTP_conf = false;
        if(file_exists($lPrefix . $lDir . '/sftp-config.json')) {
            $ST2_SFTP_conf = file_get_contents($lPrefix . $lDir . '/sftp-config.json');
            unlink($lPrefix . $lDir . '/sftp-config.json');
        }

        //Start mirror
        $lftOutput = explode("\n", shell_exec('lftp -e "mirror -e -p --parallel=10 --log=' . $archiveLocation . 'logs/' . $archiveName . '.txt ' . $rDir . '/ ' . $lPrefix . $lDir . '/; exit top" ' . $bookmark));

        //Tar regardless of lftp error or success
        $tarOutput = shell_exec('cd ' . $lPrefix . ' && tar -czf ' . $archiveLocation . $archiveName . '.tar.gz ' . $lDir);

        //Output completion or errors
        shell_exec('notify-send -i gnome-network-properties -t 0 "Mirror & Archive Complete" "' . $archiveName . '\n\n' . implode('\n', $lftOutput) . $tarOutput . '"');

        //put back ST2 SFTP conf
        if($ST2_SFTP_conf != false) file_put_contents($lPrefix . $lDir . '/sftp-config.json', $ST2_SFTP_conf);

        exit;
    }
    else shell_exec('notify-send -i error -t 0 "Mirror & Archive Error" "' . date('Y-m-d') . ' ' . date('H-i') . '\n' . $lDir . ' \n Does not exist! D:"');
}
else shell_exec('notify-send -i error -t 0 "Mirror & Archive Error" "' . date('Y-m-d') . ' ' . date('H-i') . '\n' . implode('\n', $error) . '"');
?>
```

It can be run for many sites via a short-cut like so...

```
terminator -T "Mirror & Archive" -e "php ~/Programs/mirror.php l=local-dir_path r=./ b=lftp-bookmark-name"
```

If no password is in the LFTP bookmark (there shouldn’t be as it's stored in plain text) the terminal prompts for a password, after the script has run, a nice notification is given with some info about files/folders/speed etc.

However, when the script is running in a terminal, only the "input password" bit is output to the terminal, I would like all the output displayed in the terminal (normally that would display what file/folder is currently working with etc.)

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Maybe you should catch/output the returns from your [`shell_exec()`](http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) calls? However that will only show the output *after* the command has fully completed. The way you are writing your script I don't think you'll ever be able to see it live.

Comment: Yes atm it outputs the end result, I though it might not be possible like this. Do you have any advice on how to code it better for this situation?

Answer (score 3):

IIRC the reason that you see the password prompt output to the terminal is that it is using `stderr`. You could try redirecting `stdout` to `stderr` for your commands which should show you the 'real-time' progress. Tack this on to the end of the `shell_exec()` command: `1>&2`

ie:

```
shell_exec('lftp -e "mirror -e -p --parallel=10 --log=' . $archiveLocation . 'logs/' . $archiveName . '.txt ' . $rDir . '/ ' . $lPrefix . $lDir . '/; exit top" ' . $bookmark . ' 1>&2')
```

However, this will preclude you from having anything returned by `shell_exec` for logging purposes. What I would suggest is something like:

```
$log_stem = '/tmp/' . time() . '_';  // ie: /tmp/1357581737_
$lfOutfile = $log_stem . 'lftp.log';
$tarOutfile = $log_stem . 'tar.log';

shell_exec('lftp -blah | tee ' . $lfOutfile ' 1>&2' );
shell_exec('tar -blah | tee ' . $tarOutfile ' 1>&2' );

$lfOut = file_get_contents($lfOutfile);
$tarOut = file_get_contetns(tarOutfile);

// remove tmp files
unlink($lfOutfile);
unlink($tarOutfile);
```

Which will capture a copy of the output to a file before redirecting the output to stderr so you can watch it live.

However, if you want to run this via cron I would recommend *against* writing anything to stderr that is not an error, otherwise cron will send a warning email every time it is run.

Comment: I tried that but it does not work... The script does it's job just fine but it is still not output to the terminal. http://pastebin.com/zCeNvK1s

Answer (score 0):

I think the last answer was close:

Either this:

```
shell_exec('lftp -blah |& tee ' . $lfOutfile );
shell_exec('tar -blah |& tee ' . $tarOutfile );
```

Or if that still doesn't work try this:

```
shell_exec('lftp -blah 2>&1 | tee ' . $lfOutfile );
shell_exec('tar -blah 2>&1 | tee ' . $tarOutfile );
```